# Flutter bloc listener doesn't change the loading when the state is changed

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using bloc consumer but the listener doesn't change when the new state is emitted. The way the app works is, first, login page is shown and after login button is hit the loading overlay is shown and then the notesview will be shown. But when the notesview is shown the loading overlay is not hidden. It's hidden only if I press hot restart.

**Main**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const CustomTheme(
      initialThemeKey: ThemeKeys.light,
      child: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Von Note',
      theme: CustomTheme.of(context),
      routes: {
        createUpdateNoteView: (context) => const CreateUpdateNoteView(),
      },
      home: BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
          child: const Content()),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  const Content({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(const AuthEventInitialize());
    return BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isLoading) {
          LoadingScreen().show(
            context: context,
            text: state.loadingText.toString(),
          );
        } else {
          LoadingScreen().hide();
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthStateLoggedIn) {
          return const NotesView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateNeedVerification) {
          return const VerifyEmailView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateLoggedOut) {
          return const LoginView();
        } else if (state is AuthStateRegistering) {
          return const RegisterView();
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Splash(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Bloc**

```
on<AuthEventLogIn>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AuthStateLoggedOut(
        exception: null,
        isLoading: true,
        loadingText: 'Please wait while I log you in',
      ));
      final email = event.email;
      final password = event.password;
      try {
        final user = await provider.logIn(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        if (user.isEmailVerified) {
          emit(const AuthStateLoggedOut(
            exception: null,
            isLoading: false,
          ));
          emit(AuthStateLoggedIn(
            user: user,
            isLoading: false,
          ));
        } else {
          emit(
            const AuthStateLoggedOut(
              exception: null,
              isLoading: false,
            ),
          );
          emit(const AuthStateNeedVerification(isLoading: false));
        }
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        emit(AuthStateLoggedOut(
          exception: e,
          isLoading: false,
        ));
      }
    });
```

**State**

```
class AuthStateLoggedOut extends AuthState with EquatableMixin {
  final Exception? exception;
  const AuthStateLoggedOut({
    required this.exception,
    required bool isLoading,
    String? loadingText,
  }) : super(
          isLoading: isLoading,
          loadingText: loadingText,
        );

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [exception, isLoading];
}
```

**Tree**

[image: The widget tree]

I've tried to change the props in equatable adding loadingtext but didn't work, tried to call LoadingScreen().hide in init notesview didn't work, and tried to call LoadingScreen().hide in builder if state is AuthStateLoggedIn also didn't work.

Comment: Can you try with `props => [...., identityHashCode(this)];`

Comment: Turns out i had syntax error that made the overlay didn't hide. To hide the overlay should use close() but i used only close.